# Cast Boolean object a boolean primitivo

Tags: android, booleano, cast

os pongo en contexto:

1. Estoy intentando crear una apk con tres botones y un editText. En el editText se introducen strings que se añaden a un fichero, por cada string que se añade se añade a otro fichero de la misma ruta el valor false. Después al darle al primer botón se añade al archivo, con el segundo se abre un showDialog y el tercero muestra un dialogFragment.
2. El problema es que al leer del archivo donde guardo los booleans me da fallo al castearlos a boolean(están guardados como string). El código que yo tengo para castear es el siguiente:

   ```
    for(int i=0;i<booleanos.size();i++){
       miarrayBoolean[i]= booleanos.get(i).booleanValue();
    }
   ```

Donde booleanos es el ArrayList de Booleans que leo del archivo .txt y miarrayBoolean es el array de booleans primitivos.

Esta parte me devuelve el siguiente fallo en el logcat:

```
 Process: com.example.i4b_a19alexnp_v2, PID: 5551
java.lang.ClassCastException: java.lang.String cannot be cast to java.lang.Boolean
    at com.example.i4b_a19alexnp_v2.DialogFragment.onCreateDialog(DialogFragment.java:111)
    at androidx.fragment.app.DialogFragment.onGetLayoutInflater(DialogFragment.java:380)
    at androidx.fragment.app.Fragment.performGetLayoutInflater(Fragment.java:1412)
    at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManagerImpl.java:881)
    at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveFragmentToExpectedState(FragmentManagerImpl.java:1238)
    at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManagerImpl.java:1303)
    at androidx.fragment.app.BackStackRecord.executeOps(BackStackRecord.java:439)
    at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManagerImpl.executeOps(FragmentManagerImpl.java:2079)
    at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManagerImpl.executeOpsTogether(FragmentManagerImpl.java:1869)
    at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManagerImpl.removeRedundantOperationsAndExecute(FragmentManagerImpl.java:1824)
    at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManagerImpl.execPendingActions(FragmentManagerImpl.java:1727)
    at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManagerImpl$2.run(FragmentManagerImpl.java:150)
    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5417)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:726)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616)
```

Y este es el codigo que tengo por ahora en la clase donde creo el DialogFragment:

```
package com.example.i4b_a19alexnp_v2;


public class DialogFragment extends androidx.fragment.app.DialogFragment {
File dirFicheiroSD;
File rutaCompleta;

public static String fichero = "frutas.txt";
public static String ficheroBooleans = "booleans.txt";
private static final int INPUT_PERMISO=3;
boolean sobreescribir=false;

boolean b;


public void setDirFicheiroSD(File dirFicheiroSD) {
    this.dirFicheiroSD = dirFicheiroSD;
}

public List leerStrings(){
    List<String> arlist = new ArrayList<String>();
    try {
        rutaCompleta = new File(dirFicheiroSD.getAbsolutePath(), fichero);
        BufferedReader br =new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(new FileInputStream(rutaCompleta)));
        String linea;

        while((linea=br.readLine())!= null){
            arlist.add(linea);
        }
        br.close();



    }catch (Exception e){

    }
    return arlist;
}
public List leerBooleans(){
    List<String> booleanList = new ArrayList<String>();
    try {
        rutaCompleta = new File(dirFicheiroSD.getAbsolutePath(), ficheroBooleans);
        BufferedReader br =new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(new FileInputStream(rutaCompleta)));
        String linea;

        while((linea=br.readLine())!= null){
            booleanList.add(linea);
        }
        br.close();



    }catch (Exception e){

    }
    return booleanList;
}
public void escribirBooleans(boolean bol,boolean sobreescribir){
    try {
        rutaCompleta = new File(dirFicheiroSD.getAbsolutePath(), ficheroBooleans);
        OutputStreamWriter osw = new OutputStreamWriter(new FileOutputStream(rutaCompleta, sobreescribir));

        osw.write(bol+"\n");


        osw.close();

        Log.i("Ruta", String.valueOf(getActivity().getExternalFilesDir(fichero)));
        if(bol) {
            Log.i("Contenida", "True");
        }else{
            Log.i("Contenida","False");
        }

    }catch(Exception e){
        Log.e("Interna","Error escribindo no ficheiro "+rutaCompleta);
    }

}

@NonNull
@Override
public Dialog onCreateDialog(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    ArrayList<String> frutas= (ArrayList) leerStrings();
    ArrayList<Boolean> booleanos=(ArrayList) leerBooleans();
    String[] miarray = new String[frutas.size()];
    miarray = frutas.toArray(miarray);
    boolean[] miarrayBoolean=new boolean[booleanos.size()];
    for(int i=0;i<booleanos.size();i++){
        miarrayBoolean[i]= booleanos.get(i).booleanValue();
    }
    final String[] seleccionables=miarray;
    AlertDialog.Builder builder=new AlertDialog.Builder(getActivity())
            .setTitle("Frutas")
            .setMultiChoiceItems(miarray, miarrayBoolean, new DialogInterface.OnMultiChoiceClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which, boolean isChecked) {

                }
            })
            .setPositiveButton("Aceptar", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                    sobreescribir=false;
                    for(int i=0;i<miarrayBoolean.length;i++){
                        b=miarrayBoolean[i];
                        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT <= 20) {
                            int permiso = ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(getActivity(), Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE);
                            if (permiso == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {

                                escribirBooleans(b,sobreescribir);
                            } else  {
                                if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.M) {
                                    requestPermissions(new String[]{Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE}, INPUT_PERMISO);
                                }

                            }
                        }else{
                            escribirBooleans(b,sobreescribir);
                        }

                    }
                }

            })
            .setNegativeButton("Cancelar", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {

                }
            });


       return builder.create();
    }
}
```

La finalidad es que muestre el los elementos dentro de un txt (que lo leo con el método leerStrings()) y el array de booleanos que leo y al final vuelvo a sobrescribir seria para que tanto en showDialog como en el DialogFragment tenga los mismos seleccionados por el usuario y mantenerlos aún que se cierre la apk y se apague el dispositivo. Sé que se podría hacer con bases de datos pero necesito hacerlo leyendo del archivo txt.
Muchas gracias de antemano.

Answer (score 0):

El problema es el uso de [***raw generic types***](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/rawTypes.html), un *musn't* según el libro **Effective Java** 3rd edition, por Joshua Bloch, ISBN: 9780134686097, item 26, chapter 5.

Específicamente el libro menciona que se deben de evitar debido a que si los utilizas pierdes la seguridad y otros beneficios de los tipos genéricos que provee java, además de que el código puede tener graves errores (como es tu caso) y sin embargo, compilar sin problema.

### El error

A continuación te dejo un código que muestra y explica por qué te sale el error

```java
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

class Main {
    public static List leerBooleans() {
        List<String> strings = new ArrayList<>(3);
        strings.add("true");
        strings.add("true");
        strings.add("false");
        return strings;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // booleanos REALMENTE ES UNA LISTA DE STRINGS
        // NO ES UNA LISTA DE BOOLEANOS!!!
        // DE AHÍ QUE SALGA LA EXCEPCIÓN class java.lang.String cannot be cast to class java.lang.Boolean
        // List<Boolean> booleanos = leerBooleans();

        // por otra parte, si lo intentamos así
        // esto evidentemente no los convierte a una lista de booleanos
        // SIGUE SIENDO UNA LISTA DE STRINGS!!!
        List booleanos = leerBooleans();

        // veamos si es cierto con este código
        booleanos.forEach(bool -> System.out.println(bool.getClass().getCanonicalName()));
    }
}
```

Los comentarios lo explican todo.

### La solución

Como leíste en el código anterior, eso no se arregla simplemente declarando una lista con el tipo que quieres, sin importar el tipo de dato que contenga la lista.

Debe de existir un casteo de los tipos de datos. Dicho casteo, lo puedes hacer en varios puntos de tu código, pero vamos a suponer que `leerBooleans` siempre va a regresar una lista de `String`s (en cuyo caso no hace mucho sentido el nombre del método), entonces la conversión se podría hacer algo similar a lo siguiente.

```java
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.stream.Collectors;

class Main {
    // NO usamos raw types aquí, y especificamos el tipo que contiene la lista
    public static List<String> leerBooleans() {
        List<String> strings = new ArrayList<>(3);
        strings.add("true");
        strings.add("true");
        strings.add("false");
        return strings;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // ahora sí hacemos algo que tenga sentido
        // asignamos a una variable de tipo lista de strings
        // el valor de retorno del método que regresa una lista de strings
        List<String> booleansStr = leerBooleans();

        // ahora pasamos de string a boolean cada uno de los elementos de la lista
        List<Boolean> booleans = booleansStr
            .stream()
            .map(Boolean::parseBoolean) // parseamos cada string a boolean
            .collect(Collectors.toList());

        // veamos ahora el tipo que contiene cada lista
        booleansStr.forEach(bool -> System.out.println(bool.getClass().getCanonicalName()));
        booleans.forEach(bool -> System.out.println(bool.getClass().getCanonicalName()));
    }
}
```

Y listo! Si ejecutas el código anterior, te darás cuenta que en efecto, la lista `booleansStr` **no** contiene valores booleanos, sino `String`s, mientras que la lista `booleans` **sí** contiene realmente valores booleanos.